# without actually finding them, determine the number of solutions of the congruence.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

without actually finding then, determine the number of solutions of the congruence.
$$x ^2 \equiv 3 \pmod {11^2 . 23^2}$$

My professor gave a hint of finding the order of the group of units and the solution at the back of the book is 4, but I do not know how to use the hint and how the solution is as it is? could anyone help me in understanding this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95028/discussion-on-question-by-hopefully-without-actually-finding-them-determine-the).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution which follows the direction of your professor. You can recall some thing in your another post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3255277/how-can-i-know-the-number-of-solutions-of-the-following-congruence-x-10-eq). We use the same notations in that post.

1) Let $n=11^2\cdot 23^2$. It is not hard to obtain 
$$\mathbb{Z}_{n}^*\cong \mathbb{Z}_{11^2}^*\times \mathbb{Z}_{23^2}^*\cong (C_{11} \times C_{10}) \times (C_{23} \times C_{22})=(C_{55} \times C_{2}) \times (C_{253} \times C_{2}).$$

Therefore $x^2\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ has $|1\times C_2\times 1 \times C_2|=4$ solutions. Or we can say $y^2\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ has 4 solutions, where $x,y$ are unknowns.

2) In this part, we assert that $3$ is a quadratic residue modulo $11^2$ and $23^2$, respectively. Assume that you know how to calculate the order of $3$ modulo $11^2$ and $23^2$, respectively. The result is 
$$3^{5}\equiv 1 \pmod{11^2},3^{253}\equiv 1 \pmod{23^2}.$$
Thus
$$3^{6}\equiv 3 \pmod{11^2},3^{254}\equiv 3 \pmod{23^2}.$$
Hence, one of the square root of $3$ modulo $11^2$ and $23^2$, is $3^3$ and $3^{127}$, respectively. Or if you do not what to find the square roots, then note that $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $n$ if $\mathrm{Ord}(a)$ is odd. Hence $3$ is also  a quadratic residue modulo $n$. Denote $y_0$ for one of the square root of of $3$ modulo $n$.

3) Now $x^2\equiv 3\equiv y_i^2\pmod{n}$. It is equivalent to $$\left(\frac{x}{y_0}\right)^2\equiv 1 \pmod{n}.$$ 
Let $y=\frac{x}{y_0}$. From Part 1), $y$ has 4 solution, and so is $x$. So your answer is 4.

The key is to convert the equation $x^2\equiv a\pmod{n}$ into other equation $y^2\equiv 1\pmod{n}$.

Comment: Can you help me in solving this congruence please in details? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3261754/how-can-i-solve-the-following-congruence-x2-equiv-9-pmod-23-3-52#3261759

Comment: @hopefully finding "the number of solutions" and "the set of solutions" are two different things. I think Julian Mejia explains clearly and  Chinese Remainder Theorem ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem ) would help you understand this answer.

Comment: I solved it thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let $S(f,n)$ denote the set of solutions of congruence equation $f(x)\equiv 0 \pmod{n}$ for $f=\sum_{i=0}^{m}{a_ix^i}\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  Denote $N(f,n)=|S(f,n)|$.

> Lemma 1: Let $n=\prod_{i=1}^{k}{p_i^{e_i}}$ where $p_i$ are distinct primes and
>   $e_i$ are positive integers. Then
>   $N(f,n)=\prod_{i=1}^{k}{N(f,p_i^{e_i})}$.
>
> Lemma 2: Define $f'(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{m}{ia_ix^{i-1}}$. If $S(f,p)\cap
>  S(f',p)=\emptyset$, then $N(f,p^l)=N(f,p)$, where $p$ is a prime and
>   $l$ is an positive integer.
>
> Lemma 3: $N(x^k-n,p)=\gcd(k,p-1)$ if $N(x^k-n,p)>0$ and $p\not\mid n$.

1) Put $f(x)=x^2-3$, $n=11^2\cdot 23^2$ and We have $$N(x^2-3,11^2\cdot 23^2)=N(x^2-3,11^2)\cdot N(x^2-3, 23^2)=N(x^2-3,11)\cdot N(x^2-3, 23),$$ since $S((x^2-3)',p_i)=\{0\}$ and $0\notin S(x^2-3,p_i)$.

2) To determinate $N(x^2-3, 11)$ and $N(x^2-3, 23)$, we need some results about the Legendre symbol for prime $p$,
$$\left({\frac {a}{p}}\right)={\begin{cases}1&{\text{if $x^2\equiv a\pmod{e}$ has solutions}},\\-1&{\text{if $x^2\equiv a\pmod{e}$ has no solutions}},\\0&{\text{if }}a\equiv 0{\pmod {p}}.\end{cases}}$$
In fact it is easy to calculate Legendre symbol if $p\not\mid n$. That is
$$\left({\frac {a}{p}}\right)\equiv a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\pmod{p}.$$

Using Legendre symbol, we have $\left({\frac {3}{11}}\right)\equiv 3^{\frac{11-1}{2}}\equiv 1\pmod{11}$ and $\left({\frac {3}{23}}\right)\equiv 3^{\frac{23-1}{2}}\equiv 3\cdot 9\cdot 6\equiv 1 \pmod{23}$. Note that $$3^2\equiv 9 \pmod{23},$$ $$3^4\equiv (3^2)^2 \equiv 81 \equiv 12\pmod{23},$$ $$3^8\equiv (3^4)^2 \equiv 144 \equiv 6\pmod{23},$$
Due to Lemma 3, $N(x^2-3, 11)=N(x^2-3, 23)=2$.

3) To sum up, $N(x^2-3,11^2\cdot 23^2)=2\cdot 2=4$, i.e., the congruence equation $x^2\equiv 3 \pmod{11^2\cdot 23^2}$ has 4 solutions.