# How can I solve the following congruence $x^2 \equiv 9 \pmod {2^3 . 3 . 5^2}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

How can I solve the following congruence $x^2 \equiv 9 \pmod {2^3 . 3 . 5^2}$?

The problem is that I do not know the number of solutions of $x^2 \equiv 9 \pmod { 3}$, it seems like either it is zero only or any multiple of 3 other than 0, could anyone explain for me why it is not any multiple of 3 other than 0?

Comment: Any $x\equiv 0\pmod{3}$ satisfies $x^2\equiv 9 (\equiv 0) \pmod{3}$.  That is, $x$ could be $0$, or $3$ or $6$, or $-3$, or,....

Comment: are you asking why the number of solutions is not any multiple of $3$, or why not any multiple of $3$ is a solution?

Comment: why not any multiple of 3 is a solution ? only the zero multiple is a solution? .... by the way how many solutions are there?@J.W.Tanner

Comment: $3^2\equiv9\pmod{2^3\cdot3\cdot5^2}$ but $6^2\equiv36\not\equiv9\pmod{2^3 \cdot3 \cdot5^2}$

Comment: so we have only 0 and 3 for this congruence ..... correct ? @J.W.Tanner

Comment: I will make a comment of what I think your confusion is. Usually when you want to solve a modular equation like $x^2=9\bmod 3$.  The solutions are not just $x$, but $x\bmod 3$. As you said, $x$ can be any multiple of $3$, but in that case $x\bmod 3=0\bmod 3$. So, the only solution of the equation is $0\bmod 3$, and that may be the reason that you have heard that $0$ was the only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
 x^2\equiv 9\bmod 8&\iff x\equiv 1\bmod 2\\
x^2\equiv 9\bmod 3&\iff x\equiv 0\bmod 3\\
x^2\equiv 9\bmod 25&\iff x\equiv \pm 3\bmod 25
\end{align}$$

So, $x^2\equiv 9\mod 600\iff x\equiv \pm3\bmod 150$.

So, the solutions $\pmod{600}$ are going to be $8$, namely  $\pm 3\bmod{600}$, $150\pm 3\bmod{600}$, $300\pm3\bmod{600}$, and $450\pm 3\bmod{600}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3261661/without-actually-finding-then-determine-the-number-of-solutions-of-the-congruen

Comment: The solution at the back of the book contains 8 solutions?

Comment: @hopefully makes sense they give 8 solutions because the solutions actually should be given in the original modulus $\bmod(2^3\cdot 3\cdot 5^2)=\bmod(600)$. So, the actual 8 solutions will be $\pm 3,150\pm3,300\pm 3$ and $450\pm 3$ ($\bmod 600$)

Comment: from where you got the first equivalence?

Comment: how do you remove the power from the prime in the mod ?

Comment: The third congruence has solutions 18 and 7

Comment: what are 150 , 300 and 450?

Comment: where are the 8 systems of linear congruences?

Comment: @hopefully $odd^2\equiv 1\bmod 8$ that's how I got first equivalence. $18,7$ are not solutions of the third equation. $150,300,450$ are the multiples of $150$ smaller than $600$. There are $8$ solutions $\bmod 600$ count it.( When I use $\pm$ I am actually given 2 solutions at once)